# React App Refresh Causes Redirection back to "/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am writing a web app that is built on React with a firebase backend for database and user authentication. The routing flow is basically sign in => join-conference => conference-page. However, there is also a settings page available after sign in. The issue that I am having is that when I refresh the page on the settings page, the app redirects to the sign in page. I am fairly sure the error has something to do with the `onAuthStateChanged` hook that tracks user authentication, but I cannot figure out the bug. Specifically, the bug is in ternary operator in the routing tag for the settings page (presumably because on refresh the user is signed out temporarily?) Here is that hook

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unregisterAuthObserver = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      if (!!user) {
        syncUsers(user);
        setCurrentUser(user);
        const data = await getUserData(user);
        if (data?.conferenceCode) {
          const conferenceCode = data.conferenceCode.slice(0, 6);
          setConferenceID(conferenceCode);
          }
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(null);
        setConferenceID(null);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
    return () => unregisterAuthObserver();
  }, []);
```

and for reference, here are my routing tags

```
{isLoading ? <Typography>Loading...</Typography> : (
          <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/signin"
            element={!currentUser ? <SignInScreen /> : <Navigate to="/join-conference" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/join-conference"
            element={
              !!currentUser && !conferenceID ? (
                <JoinConf user={currentUser} navigate={navigate} />
              ) : (
                <Navigate to={`/conference/${conferenceID}`} />
              )
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/conference/:confID"
            element={
              !!currentUser ? (
                !!conferenceID ? <ConfPage user={currentUser} /> : <Navigate to="/join-conference" />
              ) : (
                <Navigate to="/signin" />
              )
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/settings"
            element={
              !!currentUser ? {/* HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS */}
                <SettingsPage user={currentUser} /> :
                <Navigate to="/signin" />
            }
          />
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/signin" />} />
        </Routes>
        
          )}
```